# Why is the real time significantly greater than user + sys time of an hadoop task?

Tags: multithreading, hadoop, time, multiprocessing, virtual-machine

When running the time command on an hadoop task, the following results come:

```
real 0m25.839s
user 0m1.362s
sys  0m0.184
```

I'm running a single node on a VM and trying to note the benchmark the time for an hadoop task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming time spent sleeping for I/O isn't the cause, perhaps the fact that the VM is itself running as a process on the host is causing the large discrepancy.

The real time represents wall-clock time. The user+sys times reported here are how much time the task took on the VM's processor. Thus, reported real time would include time used by other processes running on the VM and processes besides the VM running on the host.

Comment: Running unix sort or other commands sometimes even produces greater user+sys times(due to multicores) on the same VM, hence I doubt this is the reason.